# Runtime.interop ArgumentNullException using ZXing

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, zxing, argumentnullexception

I am trying to parse a QR Code in a Windows Store-app using ZXing.Net, but when I try to run it using the latest version from their webpage it gives me a `ArgumentNullException` in `BitmapLuminanceSource.Silverlight.cs` on line 50

The line looks like this

```
var data = System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.ToArray(writeableBitmap.PixelBuffer, 0, (int)writeableBitmap.PixelBuffer.Length);
```

The `WriteableBitmap` is not null, so I do not what, what is null.

Can anybody help me?

It is from this method

```
public BitmapLuminanceSource(WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap)
   : base(writeableBitmap.PixelWidth, writeableBitmap.PixelHeight)
{
   var height = writeableBitmap.PixelHeight;
   var width = writeableBitmap.PixelWidth;
   var stride = width * 4;
   luminances = new byte[width * height];
   Color c;

#if NETFX_CORE
   var data = System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.ToArray(writeableBitmap.PixelBuffer, 0, (int)writeableBitmap.PixelBuffer.Length);
   for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
   {
      int offset = y * stride;
      for (int x = 0, xl = 0; x < stride; x += 4, xl++)
      {
         c = Color.FromArgb(
            data[x + offset], 
            data[x + offset + 1], 
            data[x + offset + 2], 
            data[x + offset + 3]);
         luminances[y * width + xl] = (byte)(0.3 * c.R + 0.59 * c.G + 0.11 * c.B + 0.01);
      }
   }
#else
   var pixels = writeableBitmap.Pixels;
   for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
   {
      int offset = y * width;
      for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
      {
         int srcPixel = pixels[x + offset];
         c = Color.FromArgb((byte)((srcPixel >> 0x18) & 0xff),
            (byte)((srcPixel >> 0x10) & 0xff),
            (byte)((srcPixel >> 8) & 0xff),
            (byte)(srcPixel & 0xff));
         luminances[offset + x] = (byte)(0.3 * c.R + 0.59 * c.G + 0.11 * c.B + 0.01);
      }
   }
#endif
}
```

**UPDATE**

The WriteableBitmat is created using this code

```
// Get the File
var File = await FilePick.PickSingleFileAsync();

// Convert the File to a Bitmap
var Stream = await File.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
var Bmp = new BitmapImage();
Bmp.SetSource(Stream);
var WBmp = new WriteableBitmap(Bmp.PixelWidth, Bmp.PixelHeight);
WBmp.SetSource(Stream);
```

By using Damir Arh's answer, the error is moved a bit to the following code

```
c = Color.FromArgb(
    data[x + offset], 
    data[x + offset + 1], 
    data[x + offset + 2], 
    data[x + offset + 3]);
```

Where I get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, when

```
x = 580
xl = 145
offset = 31104
y = 36
height = 216
width = 216
stride = 864
data = {byte[31684]}
```

I can of course see why it is out of range, but I can not see how to fix it

It was fixed using Damir Arh's updated answer with `Stream.Seek(0)`

Comment: How can we know what is `null`? Did you debug your code? What is happening when your breakpoint cross this line? If you get `NullPointerException`, you are definitly try to access a part of some `null` value.

Comment: Yes, I set up a breakpoint the line before, so I hoped somebody else have had the same problem e.g. with `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.ToArray`

Comment: Are you sure `writeableBitmap.PixelBuffer` is not `null` ?

Comment: When I set a breakpoint, it tells me the pixelbuffer is a Windows Runtime Object, and I can access the properties

Comment: I hate when single lines of code are posted when we can't possibly know what the other values are paste the relevant code for where you are using this line what method are you doing this in..

Comment: @DJKRAZE I have added the full method now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a quick port of the Silverlight example that's available from the [project homepage](https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/) and it worked:

```
var dlg = new FileOpenPicker();
dlg.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
var file = await dlg.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    currentBarcode = new WriteableBitmap(89, 89);
    using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        currentBarcode.SetSource(stream);
    }
    imgDecoderBarcode.Source = currentBarcode;
    var result = reader.Decode(currentBarcode);
    if (result != null)
    {
        txtDecoderType.Text = result.BarcodeFormat.ToString();
        txtDecoderContent.Text = result.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        txtDecoderType.Text = String.Empty;
        txtDecoderContent.Text = "No barcode found.";
    }
}
```

I also tried calling the offending line from the code you posted and there was no exception thrown:

```
var dlg = new FileOpenPicker();
dlg.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
var file = await dlg.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    currentBarcode = new WriteableBitmap(89, 89);
    using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        currentBarcode.SetSource(stream);
        var data = System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.ToArray(currentBarcode.PixelBuffer, 0, (int)currentBarcode.PixelBuffer.Length);
    }
}
```

The problem in your case is how you're creating the `WriteableBitmap` that is being passed to this method. Because you first load a `Bitmap` from the same stream you're already positioned at its end when you set it as the source for `WritableBitmap`. You need to reposition yourself to the beginning of the stream so that the data can be loaded once more:

```
// Convert the File to a Bitmap
var Stream = await File.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
var Bmp = new BitmapImage();
Bmp.SetSource(Stream);
Stream.Seek(0);
var WBmp = new WriteableBitmap(Bmp.PixelWidth, Bmp.PixelHeight);
WBmp.SetSource(Stream);
```

Comment: I created the WriteableBitmap using the code mentioned in the answer now. What is `imgDecoderBarcode` set to using your code?

Comment: @The87Boy `imgDecoderBarcode` is not relevant - it's just an `Image` control that show the image and can be safely commented out without affecting the rest of the code. The problem in your case is that you're loading two bitmaps from the same stream. I added the explanation to my answer.